# SimpleInjector InterceptWith does not work for registration via Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Simple Injector [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/) has a section that describes how to do [interception](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#interception). The [interception extensions code snippet](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html) will add the interceptor to all interfaces registered with the container matching some condition you specify.

I am using code borrowed from [Async Programming : Intercepting Asynchronous Methods Using Unity Interception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574805.aspx) and adapting it to simple injector. I add tracing to the container using

```
container.InterceptWith<TracingInterceptor>(t => 
  t.Namespace == "mynamespace" && t.IsInterface);
```

How can I get this interceptor extension to work with container registrations loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom?

```
var assemblies = 
    from file in new DirectoryInfo(pluginDir).GetFiles()
    where file.Name.StartsWith("Proj.Plugin.", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    where file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll"
    select Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);

var registrations = (
    from assembly in assemblies 
    from type in assembly.GetTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(type) || typeof(IBar).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(type, container))
    .ToArray();

container.RegisterCollection<IFoo>(
    registrations.Where(r => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(r.ImplementationType)));
container.RegisterCollection<IBar>(
    registrations.Where(r => typeof(IBar).IsAssignableFrom(r.ImplementationType)));
```

**EDIT:**

In assembly A

```
public class FooCommand {
  ...
}
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> {
  Task Handle(TCommand command);
}
public class ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand> {
  ...
}
```

In assembly B which has reference to assembly A

```
public class FooCommandHandler<FooCommand> : ICommandHandler<FooCommand> {
  public async Task Handle(FooCommand command) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In assembly C

```
public class TracingInterceptor : IInterceptor {
  ...
}
```

In assembly D which has reference to assembly A and C only

```
public static class Bootstrapper {
  private static Container _container;
  public static void Bootstrap() {
    ...
    var assemblies = from file in new DirectoryInfo(pluginDir).GetFiles()
      where (file.Name.StartsWith("assemblyB.", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
      where file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll"
      select Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
    _container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies, Lifestyle.Scoped);

    _container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);

    _container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    _container.InterceptWith<TracingInterceptor>(t =>
      t.Namespace.StartsWith("NS.", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
      && t.IsInterface);
  }
}

public class Foo : IFoo {
  public Foo(ICommandHandler<FooCommand> fooCommand) {
    _fooCommnad = fooCommand;
  }

  private readonly ICommandHandler<FooCommnad> _fooCommand;

  public async Task Bar() {
    await _fooCommand.Handle(new FooCommand());
  }
}
```

The call to Foo.Bar is correctly intrercepted but not the calls to ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator.Handle or FooCommandHandler.Handle... I don't care if the interceptor does not intercept the decorator but the decorate should be intercepted

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce your issue, but after copying your example code the interceptor is simply applied. You are doing something wrong that you don't show in the code in your question.

Comment: Updated the question. I am also using decorators, while I can add decorators to some of the generic interfaces I cant add a Tracing*Decorator to all interfaces and thus using interception for tracing. Hope the edit helps clarify my scenario

Comment: Even with your update, I can't reproduce this. Check the predicate you use to apply the interceptor. I think the predicate accidentally filters out your handlers. Do note that that `InterceptWith` works much like `RegisterDecorator` works: it will only get applied once and the order in which you make the registrations matters. If you call `InterceptWith` after `RegisterDecorator` the interceptor will wrap the decorator, otherwise it will wrap the decoratee.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but if you (can) use decorators why do you need an interceptor to do interception. The decorator pattern is IMO far more powerful and clear for doing interception!

Comment: For some insanely weird reason implementations of ICommandHandlers were being filtered out by the predicate. Thanks for the help :)